# Django- Dependent Dropdown Form results in "invalid choice" on POST

Tags: django

I'm using this tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

to add a dependent dropdown to my form, but when I post the data it comes back form invalid with an invalid choice error.

In my form's **init** override, if I eliminate the dropdown queryset then it works, but that defeats the purpose.

My view:

```
def add_have(request, id=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("User: {}".format(request.user))
        for key, value in request.POST.items():
            print('{}: {}'.format(key, value) )
        form = HaveForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.profile = request.user
            model_instance.save()
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            print("FORM IS INVALID")
        return redirect('display_have_list')
    else:
        form = HaveForm()
        return render(request, 'add_have.html', {'form': form})
```

My form:

```
class HaveForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Have
        fields = ['category', 'item']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].queryset=Category.objects.all()
        self.fields['item'].queryset = Items.objects.none()
```

My Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

class Have(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey('users.Profile', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey('Items', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

The error message I'm getting implies that it's not loading the item:

```
web_1  | User: <my_username>
web_1  | csrfmiddlewaretoken: <my_token>
web_1  | category: 1
web_1  | item: 4496
web_1  | <ul class="errorlist"><li>item<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
web_1  | FORM IS INVALID
web_1  | [31/Jul/2019 09:01:24] "POST /trade/add_have/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
web_1  | [31/Jul/2019 09:01:24] "GET /trade/display_have_list/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2638
web_1  | [31/Jul/2019 09:01:24] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1767
```

If I elimitante the item queryset from the init, then it saves just fine.  I know the issue is somewhere in the way I'm initializing the form, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing your models may help point to an answer. What I am guessing is that 
field item in your model does not allow a null value. 
When you do self.fields['item'].queryset = Items.objects.none() and then use the form the value for Items will be null and to form will be invalid.

You can change the field to allow null and then you can continue on incrementally implementing the example.

Also, assuming category is a Foreign key, self.fields['category'].queryset=Category.objects.all() is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your input.
The models are fairly simple, but if the self.fields['item'].queryset = Items.objects.none()  line sets the item to null, then that just reinforces my initial thought that about what it's doing.  The real question is how to I get the dropdown to function on a non-post request for the form, i.e. the queryset is null, but submit the actual selected item for a POST function, which would have the desired behavior....

Comment: Ah looking at your models (and re-looking at his step by step instructions) I see where you are.  How is your post posting the item=4496  Item should be Null. (Since you cleared out all the options.)  I'd check what is going on in the template you are using and see if something is going on in there.